# Android Kotlin String toDouble() unresolved reference

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, type-conversion, tostring

I created a new android project (API 19 KitKat) and I am just trying to convert a string to a double via the toDouble() function.
However, android studio marks the toDouble() call as an unresolved reference.
Here is my onCreate function:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val str = "3"
    val strDouble = str.toDouble()

}
```

Apparently, android studio lets me compile and build the app anyway.
If I change the toDouble() call to something like "toDoubles()" which is a function that truly doesn't exist then the code wont compile at all.

Here are my two build.gradle files:

Project:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.10' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Module:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.tiptime"
        minSdk 19
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: you cant convert string toDouble if you are not sure that string is double.
you should check if the string isNumeric before you call toDouble(). 

fun isNumeric(toCheck: String): Boolean {
    val regex = "-?[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?".toRegex()
    return toCheck.matches(regex)
}

Comment: i think there might be something wrong with my kotlin and/or android sdk because my android studio doesn't even recognize the "toRegex()" and "matches" functions.
I created the same project on another computer and my code runs fine there.

Comment: Ok I fixed the code snippet and now the app runs fine even with the toDouble() call but android studio still doesn't recognize the functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so uninstalling Android Studio Bumblebee and installing the up-to-date Chipmunk version has fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

3 isn't a double, it's an int.
Try with "3.00" or 3.00d

Comment: try {
  a = Double.parseDouble(str);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
  //the parseDouble failed 
}